# Expect spy function to have been called with array of certain length

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I am **spying** a function in a method that receives an array as its main parameter. The **content** of that array is **irrelevant** for me. What I want to check is the **length of that array parameter**.

```js
// Main function
public async removeUsers() {
  const inactiveUsers = await this.userRepository.find({ where: { inactive: true } })

  this.userRepository.remove(inactiveUsers)
}

// Test case
const spyUserRepositoryRemove = sinon.spy(UserRepository.prototype, 'remove')
[...]
expect(spyDealRepositoryRemove).to.have.been.calledOnceWith(/* Array of length X */)
```

Is there a way of doing this with *chai* or *jest*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sinon: `spy.args` ([Reference](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/#spyargs));

And check array length / size using chai: `.lengthOf` ([Reference](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_lengthof)).

For example: (I use chai expect)

```js
// Make sure spy called.
expect(spyDealRepositoryRemove.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
// spyDealRepositoryRemove.args[0]: store all arguments used for first call.
// spyDealRepositoryRemove.args[0][0]: store 1st argument on first call.
// Make sure that 1st argument on 1st call is array!
expect(spyDealRepositoryRemove.args[0][0]).to.be.an('array');
// Verify: array length; for example: 2 members.
expect(spyDealRepositoryRemove.args[0][0]).to.have.lengthOf(2);
```